# Is org.geotools.geometry.jts.GeometryBuilder thread safe?

Tags: java, geotools, jts

Is the JTS variant of GeoTools' GeometryBuilder (`org.geotools.geometry.jts.GeometryBuilder`) thread safe? It's unclear from the [documentation](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/geometry/jts/GeometryBuilder.html) although the non-JTS GeometryBuilder [does hint that it's not thread safe](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/geometry/GeometryBuilder.html).

> The main advantage a "builder" has over a factory is that it does not
>   have to be thread safe and can hold state in order to make your job
>   easier.

Comment: If it says "it does not have to be thread safe" then assume it isn't.

Comment: That's for `org.geotools.geometry.GeometryBuilder`, `org.geotools.geometry.jts.GeometryBuilder` makes no such assertion

Comment: If it makes no assertion, then assume it isn't.

Comment: you'd need to check the code to be sure, but probably.